# How to display the logged information on an aerospike server as a graph?

Tags: graphite, aerospike, asgraphite

I would like to log some stats on some aerospike nodes and analyse the same.

I found that aerospike comes with this tool called asgraphite, which seems to be using a forked version of the

The [integration guide of asgraphite](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/monitor/graphite) mentions some commands which are supposed to, e.g., start logging. I can run the following command already on my node and see the expected output, so it looks like I am all set to start logging -

By the way, we are running the community edition, which, it seems, does not provide historical latency stats in the AMC dashboard.
    python /opt/aerospike/bin/asgraphite --help

However, I don't see any information on how to monitor the data hence logged. I am expecting a web interface which is usually provided by graphite, like this -

[image]

Comment: The picture is of a Grafana chart. Graphite's own charts are much uglier.

Head on over to Grafana's [documentation](http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/graphite/) on how to implement a dashboard on top of Graphite.

Comment: Richard, that should be an answer, not a comment :)